# Group "Discussion" software?

Tags: forum, looking-for-a-script, social-media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

My client wants a "lite" forum... not unlike these stack exchange sites, but even a little lighter.

There's a screenshot of the discussion group she likes most, below. You can also go [here](http://www.diabeticconnect.com/discussions) to see it for yourself it you like. I don't think traditional forum apps will display, functionally, in this manner.

**Is there any software I can use to get a similar result? A web service would be acceptable as well.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of good answers here. I eventually found a wordpress theme called "Askit!" from [Elegant Themes](http://elegantthemes.com) that did the trick. It's not perfect, but it's pretty good. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling "lite" is pretty sophisticated compared to typical forum software.  Both stackexchange and the Alliance Health evidence a lot of care in design; they may be deceptively simple looking.  You might try emailing feedback@alliancehealth.com (or webmaster@ or postmaster@) to see if they'll tell you what software they're using, but I'd guess it is custom software and not available generally.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest it wasn't excellent. Just that it has a lighter feel than a forum. But yeah, I don't think I want to ask them specifically, I looked it up and found some tidbits that it was indeed, completely custom.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.vanillaforums.org: it's not exactly like that site but it has some similar features, and is "lite".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Drupal](http://drupal.org), it's not specifically forum software it's a generic CMS but has forum modules available for download. Because it's a CMS you can make it has heavy or lite as you like, and customise the themes.